# Last Year Measure not displaying on grid when filtered

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am developing a dashboard on Power BI and i need to create a last year measure based on column `FIELD MEASURE`. The time level of the tale is `DAY_ID (date)`, so i made a measure using

`CALCULATE(TABLE1 [FIELD_MEASURE],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(TABLE1[DAY_ID].[Date]))`

But when i try to filter based on a integer column called `cd_mes` the new metric just doesnt display on the grid. What could be the problem? The image is a little DER to help understand the problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Sorry if my english is not good enough to understand the problem.

Comment: This has something to do with MySQL?

Comment: Hi Strawberry.

Both tables are from a MariaDB server, so i thought maybe Power BI could have some problems with the data from it. Then i realized that couldn't be the case, but i forgot to delete the tag.

Comment: Might be worth removing the tag

Comment: Ty for removing it, i saild to myself "i will remove the tag after this" and completely fogot about it.

Comment: How are you trying to filter using cd_mes in PowerBI?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to use `SUM()` inside of `CALCULATE()`

Try:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE1[FIELD_MEASURE]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(TABLE1[DAY_ID].[Date]))
```

or

```
CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE1[FIELD_MEASURE]),DATEADD(TABLE1[DAY_ID].[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

Comment: Or if Field_Measure is a custom measure then dies the table name need removing?

Comment: Hi  @whytheq.

Field_measure is a custom measure (sum_field1). I tried what you suggested but it didn't work, i mean the problem is stil the same, the measure will not show. If i come with a solution i will make you know. Im running low on ideas, so i think i will try a workaround on this.